# Removing a specific logger object in python logging

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logging, error-handling, python-logging

I am trying to suppress all the elasticsearch logging from my output and keep all the other logging in my code. I have tried setting elasticsearch logging level to warning as it is explained here [How to set the logging level for the elasticsearch library differently to my own logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842275/how-to-set-the-logging-level-for-the-elasticsearch-library-differently-to-my-own) , and [Python logging, how to filter a specific logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126663/python-logging-how-to-filter-a-specific-logger) , but it is not working for me.

Alternatively, if there was an option to remove certain logger objects it would have fixed my issue, like this one here: https://bugs.python.org/issue34199

I want to remove all these POST status messages in this output:
[out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SWKW.png)

```
import logging

path = os.getcwd()
file_path = os.path.join(path, "operations.log")
tracer = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch')
tracer.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, encoding="utf-8", format="%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s", handlers=[logging.FileHandler(file_path), logging.StreamHandler()])
```

I am expecting a method like logging.deleteLogger("logger object name")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems right.  Rather than delete a logger, you want to set its value so that log messages from that logger are suppressed.  This is what you are doing.

Here's a simple test of your code that shows that it's working as expected:

```
import logging
import os

path = "/tmp"
file_path = os.path.join(path, "operations.log")
tracer = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch')
tracer.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, encoding="utf-8", format="%(name)s %(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s", handlers=[logging.FileHandler(file_path), logging.StreamHandler()])

tracer.error("ERROR")
tracer.debug("DEBUG")
tracer.warning("WARNING")
```

Result:

```
elasticsearch 2022-12-08 21:52:36,261: ERROR: ERROR
elasticsearch 2022-12-08 21:52:36,261: WARNING: WARNING
```

Note that the `DEBUG` log message is suppressed

I can think of two things to have you check...

1. `tracer.setLevel(logging.WARNING)` means you'll still get `WARNING` and `ERROR` messages for the `elasticsearch` logger (as demonstrated above).  You'll only be suppressing `INFO` and `DEBUG` messages.  Maybe that's what you want, but you don't state that clearly.  When I want to suppress all logging levels, I set the level of the logger to `SEVERE`.  Nobody seems to use that level, so it is in effect saying to suppress all levels.  I don't know of a formal way to suppress all logging levels.  You usually don't want to suppress even `ERROR` messages anyway, so I often use either `ERROR` or `WARNING`.
2. Make sure that "elasticsearch" is the name of the logger you want to suppress.  It could be something different, like "com.elasticsearch" or some other variation.  Note how I added the `%(name)s` format specifier to the logging format so that the logger name is displayed.  You can add this to your own format specifier at least temporarily to be sure that you are suppressing the right logger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer has helped me to filter the log messages. The problem was with the logger object name. But is there actually any way to delete the logger object we want? like logger.deleteLogger("logger object name") or is  there any workaround?

Comment: Why do you want to delete the logger?  If you could do that, then when the Elasticsearch package tried to log using that logger, it might fail because you've deleted its logger.  All loggers should be free to exist.  As a consumer of the log messages, your code should simply suppress the output of loggers it doesn't want to see log messages from, as your code is already doing.

Comment: To completely ignore the logging messages from that logger, rather than just setting a level to suppress. That's why I wanted to delete the logger. But like you said, all loggers should be free to exist then what I want is not possible.